# How to plot a two-variable function in 2D?

Tags: plotting, manipulate

Say I have a function $y = ax^2$. I want a plot of '$y$' vs '$x$'. Here '$a$' is a parameter. I can set different values of '$a$'and get some disjoint set of plots by the following command:

`Plot[{1*x^2, 2*x^2, 3*x^2},{x,0,10}]`

where, I set $a= 1,2,3$ values. But the plots here are disjoint as $a$ does not take continuous values. What I want is to get a plot of '$y$' vs '$x$' by varying '$a$' continuously between $1$ to $3$. How do I do this?

Note that `DensityPlot[a*x^2,{x,0,10},{a,1,3}]` gives a plot with '$a$' as y-axis and '$x$' as x-axis. This is not what I want. Also using the command `Manipulate[Plot[a*x^2,{x,0,10}],{a,1,3}]` we get a moving picture. Again not what I need.

I hope I could make it clear, what is my requirement. I could not find this problem online. I have seen this can be done in some papers. Any ideas?

Comment: It is not clear what you want. You have 3 variables. I would have proposed Plot3D, but you said you do not want "a" as an axis?

Comment: As @DanielHuber sugested, isn't this what you want? https://reference.wolfram.com/language/howto/PlotFunctionsOfTwoVariables.html

Comment: No. These are not what I need. I am aware of Plot3D. I need the plot to be in 2D. See the [link](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2006.14252.pdf). Go to page 8. Figure 4 will make things more clear. There $\zeta_Q/\zeta$ has been plotted as a function of $\alpha$ by varying the parameter $z$ from 1 to 10.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try [`ParametricPlot`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ParametricPlot.html):

```
ParametricPlot[{x, a x^2}, {x, 0, 10}, {a, 1, 3}, AspectRatio -> 1]
```

[image]

You can highlight lines corresponding to specific values of `a` using the options [`MeshFunctions`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MeshFunctions.html) and [`Mesh`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Mesh.html):

```
alist = {1, 2, 3};
colors = Opacity[1, #] & /@ {Red, Green, Purple};
mesh = Thread[{alist, Directive[Thick, #] & /@ colors}];

ParametricPlot[{x, a x^2}, {x, 0, 10}, {a, 1, 3}, AspectRatio -> 1, 
 PlotStyle -> LightOrange,
 BoundaryStyle -> None,
 MeshFunctions -> {#4 &},
 Mesh -> {mesh},
 PlotLegends -> 
  LineLegend[colors, alist, LegendLabel -> Style["a = ", 16]]]
```

[image]

Comment: Okay. This perfect. Thanks alot.

Comment: @SamapanBhadury, my pleasure. Thank you for the accept.

Comment: Thanks. This was a great.

Answer (score 3):

Here we give an example which `Filling` not alway easy handle.So we have to use `ParametricPlot` or `ParametricRegion`

```
f[x_, a_] = Sin[x + a] ((a - 1) (a - 3) + x);
curves = Plot[Table[f[x, a], {a, 1, 3, .1}] // Evaluate, {x, -2, 2}, 
   AspectRatio -> 1];
region = ParametricPlot[{x, f[x, a]}, {a, 1, 3}, {x, -2, 2}, 
   PlotStyle -> Directive[Opacity[0.2], Yellow]];
Show[curves, region]
```

[image]

Comment: Why do you say that `Filling` doesn't work? `Plot[Table[f[x, a], {a, 1, 3, .5}] // Evaluate, {x, -2, 2}, AspectRatio -> 1, Filling -> {3 -> {5}}, FillingStyle -> LightYellow]`

Comment: @BobHanlon Thanks your example. You can test my update example.

Comment: `f[x_, a_] = Sin[x + a] ((a - 1) (a - 3) + x); Plot[Table[f[x, a], {a, 1, 3, .5}] // Evaluate, {x, -2, 2}, AspectRatio -> 1, Filling -> {1 -> {5}, 4 -> {5}, 3 -> {4}}, FillingStyle -> LightRed]`

Comment: @BobHanlon  `a=2.8` ,`Plot[f[x, 2.8], {x, -2, 2}, AspectRatio -> 1, PlotStyle -> Black]` is not all in the filling region `Filling -> {1 -> {5}, 4 -> {5}, 3 -> {4}}`

Answer (score 3):

Based on @kglr's answer, but using the option `ColorFunction` in `ParametricPlot`. Basically the arguments of `ColorFunction` are the actual Cartesian coordinates (which I have called `xx` and `yy`) followed by the parameter variables (in this case `x` and `a`):

```
{xMin, xMax} = {0, 10};
{aMin, aMax} = {1, 3};
ital[str_] := Style[str, Italic];
ParametricPlot[
  {x, a x^2}
  , {x, xMin, xMax}
  , {a, aMin, aMax}
  , AspectRatio -> 1 / GoldenRatio
  , ColorFunction -> Function[{xx, yy, x, a}, Hue[a]]
  , FrameLabel -> ital /@ {"x", "y"}
  , LabelStyle -> Directive[Black, 14]
  , RotateLabel -> False
  , PlotLabel -> ital["y"] == ital["a"] ital["x"]^2
  , PlotLegends -> Placed[
      BarLegend[{Hue, {aMin, aMax}}
        , LegendLabel -> ital["a"]
        , LegendLayout -> "Column"
      ],
      After
    ]
]
```

[image: ParametricPlot with filling based on the value of a]

Answer (score 2):

After the answer by @kglr I found another solution:

`Plot[{x^2, 3*x^2}, {x, 0, 10}, Filling -> {1 -> {2}}]`

This generates:[image]

Comment: `Manipulate[Plot[{3 x^2, a*x^2, x^2}, {x, 0, 10}, PlotStyle -> {Dashed, Automatic, Dashed}, Filling -> {1 -> {3}}, PlotLegends -> Placed[{3 x^2, a*x^2, x^2}, {0.3, 0.6}]], {{a, 1.5}, 1, 3, 0.05, Appearance -> "Labeled"}]`